# Is there an equivalent to Python's islice in Scala?

Tags: java, python, scala, functional-programming

In Python I can easily easily slice or truncate an infinite sequence with itertools's slice method:

```
list(islice(count(), 3, 5)) -> [3,4]
```

Is there an equivalent syntax in Scala that can slice or truncate an infinite stream or iterator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Oh, it looks rather simple!

```
val s = Stream.from(1).iterator
s.slice(0,19).toList
```

Comment: Or `Iterator.from(1)`